# How does nginx improve web server performance?

Tags: performance, nginx

I saw that lots of people are using nginx to improve performance of their server (even Facebook is using it). I want to know how it does that. I don't want implementation details. Just enough detail so that I can use it confidently.

Comment: Please see [this](http://serverfault.com/a/86691) answer on ServerFault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/apache_vs_nginx:

Apache is a process-based server, while nginx is an event-based web server.

The main advantage of the asynchronous approach is scalability. In a process-based server, each simultaneous connection requires a thread which incurs significant overhead. An asynchronous server, on the other hand, is event-driven and handles requests in a single (or at least, very few) threads.

While a process-based server can often perform on par with an asynchronous server under light loads, under heavier loads they usually consume far more RAM which significantly degrades performance. Also, they degrade much faster on less powerful hardware or in a resource-restricted environment such as a VPS.

Pulling numbers from thin air for illustrative purposes, serving 10,000 simultaneous connections would probably only cause Nginx to use a few megabytes of RAM whereas Apache would probably consume hundreds of megabytes (if it could do it at all).

nginx is faster at serving static files and consumes much less memory for concurrent requests because Nginx is event-based it doesn't need to spawn new processes or threads for each request, so its memory usage is very low. Wordpress.com has found nginx to be the only load balancer able to handle 8000 live traffic requests per second.

"I currently have nginx doing reverse proxy of over tens of millions of HTTP requests per day (thats a few hundred per second) on a *single server*. At peak load it uses about 15MB RAM and 10% CPU on my particular configuration (FreeBSD 6).
Under the same kind of load, apache falls over (after using 1000 or so processes and god knows how much RAM), pound falls over (too many threads, and using 400MB+ of RAM for all the thread stacks), and lighty *leaks* more than 20MB per hour (and uses more CPU, but not significantly more)."